# Using echo inside a HTML input value

Tags: php, html, forms, input, echo

I have the following code, copied exactly from a exercise from a PHP book. I am having a problem with the value attribute which contains a php echo statement. According to the book, the first time the page is loaded the input boxes should be empty because the variables won't contain any data. Instead, I see something like this:

```
<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: investment in     <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\book_apps\ch02_future_value\index.php</b> on line <b>20</b><br />.
```

Any suggestions?

```
<form action="display_results.php" method="post">

    <div id="data">
        <label>Investment Amount:</label>
        <input type="text" name="investment"
               value="<?php echo $investment; ?>"/><br />

        <label>Yearly Interest Rate:</label>
        <input type="text" name="interest_rate"
               value="<?php echo $interest_rate; ?>"/><br />

        <label>Number of Years:</label>
        <input type="text" name="years"
               value="<?php echo $years; ?>"/><br />
    </div>

    <div id="buttons">
        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="submit" value="Calculate"/><br />
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: It's probably a very old book. Which version of PHP is it teaching?

Comment: It's not only empty, it's undefined. Maybe your book was written for a less picky version of PHP.

Comment: The book is not old, it was published in 2010; it's "Murach's PHP and MySQL".

Comment: I replaced the php statement with <?php if (!empty($investement)) {echo $investement;} ?> and it seems to work properly now.

Comment: Is `$investment` ever created/defined? You're probably trying to echo a nonexisting variable. PS: you can use a shorthand of that if-statement: `<?php echo (!empty($investment) ? $investment : ""); ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are expecting the `register_globals` directive to be set, while it is not.

This means you have to get `$_POST['investement']` instead of `$investment` and you need to first check if it's been submitted:

```
$investment = array_key_exists('investment', $_POST) ? $_POST['investment'] : "";
```